# Recursively remove None value or None key from nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

**Question:**

How can I iterate over a dictionary and remove `None` keys or values from it?

Here is what I've tried:

**Code:**

```py
import copy


def _ignore(data):
    copied_data = copy.deepcopy(data)

    print('-------------------------')
    print(f'copied_data: {copied_data}')
    print('-------------------------')

    if isinstance(copied_data, list):
        print(f'item is instance of list: {copied_data}')

        for idx, item in enumerate(data):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                return _ignore(item)

            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                return _ignore(item)

            elif item is None:
                del copied_data[idx]

    elif isinstance(copied_data, dict):
        print(f'item is instance of dict: {copied_data}')

        for key, item in data.items():
            if isinstance(item, list):
                return _ignore(item)

            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                return _ignore(item)

            elif item is None:
                del copied_data[key]

    return copied_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]}

    print(f'output: {_ignore(data=data)}')
```

**Input:**

```py
{'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

**Output:**

```py
-------------------------
copied_data: {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
-------------------------
item is instance of dict: {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
-------------------------
copied_data: {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}
-------------------------
item is instance of dict: {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}
output: {'k2': 2}
```

> **Keep in mind** that the code also should remove `None` values in a nested `list` or nested `dict` and we can't remove an element from `dict` while we are iterating over it.

**Update:**
The code should support nested `dict` or `list`

**Here is another input sample:**

```py
{'key1': None, None:1 ,'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2},
        'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to alter the existing *dict*? Can;t you return another one?

Comment: Will there be a `dict` inside the `list` ?

Comment: @hansolo yes it can be

Comment: @CristiFati Its' possible I just want to remove None value and key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing what you're claiming to do, since you're only removing `None` values as far as I can see. This dict:

```py
{'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Only has `None` values, not keys. I'm gonna insist on the Python definition of keys and values here. A `None` key looks like:

```py
{None: "value"}
```

However, you could easily do it something like this:

```py
def recursive_filter(item, *forbidden):
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return [recursive_filter(entry, *forbidden) for entry in item if entry not in forbidden]
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        result = {}
        for key, value in item.items():
            value = recursive_filter(value, *forbidden)
            if key not in forbidden and value not in forbidden:
                result[key] = value
        return result
    return item
```

Which you can use like:

```py
clean = recursive_filter(dirty, None)
```

Or if you want to filter out more:

```py
clean = recursive_filter(dirty, *iterable_of_forbidden_things)
clean = recursive_filter(dirty, None, other_forbidden_thing)
```

If you really only care about values, then you can just remove the checks about the keys.

Comment: could you test it with ``{'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2},'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}``?

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi Apologies, works now. No longer attempting to hash values.

Comment: Thanks, but what about ``dirty={'key1': None, None: 1, 'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2},
         'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}`` the clean code: ``{'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
``

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi Better now. And I tested it. It all works now.

Comment: This is great! It is matching against a `list` directly though, and if you wanted it to be broadened to include, for example, a tuple, you could use `isinstance(item, (list, tuple)`. Or, you could go even broader with `isinstance(item, typing.Sequence)`or `isinstance(item, collections.abc.Collection)`, which will match a range of objects stemming from those bases!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it by creating new objects.

```
def removed_none(obj):
    t = type(obj)
    if issubclass(t, (tuple, list, set)):
        obj = t(removed_none(a) for a in obj if a is not None)
    elif issubclass(t, dict):
        obj = {k: removed_none(v) for k, v in obj.items()
               if k is not None and v is not None}
    return obj

data = {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': {1: 2, 3: None}},
        'key3': [None, [1, None, 0], 2, 3, 4]}
print(f'output: {removed_none(data)}')
# output: {'key2': {'k2': {1: 2}}, 'key3': [[1, 0], 2, 3, 4]}
```

If you want to modify the existing object in place, here is a different function (`remove_none` instead of `removed_none`). Note this cannot be use to modify tuples containing `None` values, as these are immutable.

```
def remove_none(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i in range(len(obj) - 1, -1, -1):
            if obj[i] is None:
                del obj[i]
            else:
                remove_none(obj[i])
    elif isinstance(obj, set):
        obj.discard(None)
        for elem in obj:
            remove_none(elem)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in list(obj.items()):
            if k is None or v is None:
                del obj[k]
            else:
                remove_none(v)

data = {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': None, 'k2': {1: 2, 3: None}},
        'key3': [None, [1, None, 0], 2, 3, 4]}
remove_none(data)
print(f'output: {data}')
# output: {'key2': {'k2': {1: 2}}, 'key3': [[1, 0], 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, what about nested `dict` and `list`?

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi Works for nested structures too in both cases (just fixed an error in the first function). I updated with an example.

Comment: I appreciate you, but for this input ``{'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2},'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}``, the does not work as I expected.

Comment: @MohammadMasoumi You're right, the `if None in obj:` in the first function was wrong, thanks for the feedback. It should work fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You could recursively check and return a `key, value` pair, and then create a new `dict` from it like,

```
$ cat rmnone.py
data = {'key1': None, 'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [None, 1, 23], 'k4': None}, 'k2': 2},
        'key3': [{'key1': None, 'key2': [None, 1, 2, 3], 'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}

def func(data):
    for key, val in data.items():
        if val is not None:
            if isinstance(val, list):
                tmp = []
                for v in val:
                    if isinstance(v, dict):
                        for k,v in func(v):
                            tmp.append({k:v})
                    elif v is not None:
                        tmp.append(v)
                yield (key, tmp)
            if isinstance(val, tuple):
                tmp = []
                for v in val:
                    if isinstance(v, dict):
                        for k,v in func(v):
                            tmp.append({k:v})
                    elif v is not None:
                        tmp.append(v)
                yield (key, tmp)
            elif isinstance(val, dict):
                    tmp = {}
                    for k,v in func(val):
                        tmp.update({k:v})
                    yield key, tmp
            elif not isinstance(val, (tuple, dict, list)):
                yield key,val

d = {k:v for k,v in func(data)}
print(d)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 rmnone.py
{'key2': {'k1': {'k3': [1, 23]}, 'k2': 2}, 'key3': [{'key2': [1, 2, 3]}, {'key3': {'k1': 1}}, 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: what is the ``newdata`` variable? , I think you miss it